# NetBeans not starting after installing SimpleCodeMetrics plugin

Tags: netbeans

I installed the Simple Code Metrics plugin and now the NetBeans 7.2 IDE would not start.(http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/9494/simple-code-metrics)    Please help.

Comment: First of all, installing a plugin that was intended to be installed in an age-old Netbeans version is quite often asking for trouble.  Now, how to solve this.  Please find [the Netbeans log file](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqLogMessagesFile) and post relevant parts in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases it will be possible to manually disable the plugin to allow NetBeans to start correctly.

As a first step I'd try the procedure outlined [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/gridbag/entry/disabling_a_netbeans_plugin_before), which says:

1. Go to /.netbeans/config/Modules
2. Find .xml and open it in your editor and change the "enabled" property. The plugin name for my case was com-sun-sps-devtools-commentator and so I fired up gedit and opened com-sun-sps-devtools-commentator.xml and modified the "enabled" property (marked in red box in the figure below) to make it false.
3. Ran Netbeans, it started without a problem.

A next step would be to manually remove all files related to that plugin in the /.netbeans directory.

And as a last resort, you could rename /.netbeans/7.2 to allow Netbeans a clean start, but be aware that you will have to reconfigure NetBeans from scratch after that.